# Android singleTop Activity issue

Tags: android, android-activity, launchmode

I declared my activity as **singleTop** in the manifest file. 
I am passing some value with intent when I launching this activity.

```
Intent i= new Intent(A.this,MysingleTopActivity.class);
i.putExtra("isActive",true);
startActivity(i);
```

same steps I am doing for restart activity from class B.

```
Intent i= new Intent(B.this,MysingleTopActivity.class);
i.putExtra("isActive",false);
startActivity(i);
```

so for this I am getting call in `onNewIntent()` method of MysingleTopActivity.  with `isActive =false`.

but if I rotate the screen then `onCreate()` will call and in that "isActive=true".

how can I retrieve current instance value of that activity?

Thanks

Comment: Did you setIntent in onNewIntent ?

Comment: @Parth You need to set the intent inside onNewIntent() method to get updated intent next time

Comment: No i didn't set intent inside onNewIntent()  method. I  tried with the set intent it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please answer your own question and accept the answer. That will help others and get this off the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For achieving this result need to add

```
setIntent(newintent);
```

in `onNewIntent(Intent newintent) {}` methold so on rotation of screen newintent will delivered on onCreate();

sample code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
//add your code
}
```